# Batch file to get sql backup scripts

Tags: sql, file, batch-file, backup

Is there any way where I can use Batch files to get backup of the selected scripts from the SQL database...?

Say - I have one stored procedure, one function and one view in a folder.

sp1.sql
vie1.sql
fn1.sql

Before run the batch file I want to take the backup of these files.

Kindly note: I do not want to take entire database backup. Just the provided scripts alone.
Help me to achieve this one pls...

Answer (score 0):

The specific answer depends entirely on the flavor of your database engine. But the general answer is you need to SELECT the definition from your database's data catalog (*meta data*). The function and procedure definition will probably come out intact. But the view definition may come out as just the SELECT statement - you might have to prefix it with the CREATE VIEW XXXXXXX AS part.